# ¿Cómo convertir un tipo "Image" a "Uint8List() en flutter?

Tags: imagen, flutter, conversión-de-tipos, sharedpreferences, bufferedimage

estoy haciendo un programa con flutter y necesito convertir una "Imagen" a "Uint8List". Genero el código QR (lo devuelve en "Imagen" y para compartir esta imagen debo convertirlo a "Uint8List"). Soy nuevo en aleteo, gracias. Las funciones las llamo de diferentes clases. Bibliotecas que uso: import 'package: qr_utils / qr_utils.dart'; import 'package: flutter_share_file / flutter_share_file.dart'; https://pub.dev/packages/esys_flutter_share

https://pub.dev/packages/qr_utils#-readme-tab-

```
import 'package:esys_flutter_share/esys_flutter_share.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart';
import 'package:qr_app_completa/generarQR/generarQR.dart';

class ShareData{  
    Future<Image> obtenerQRimagen(String data) async{
        Image image = await QrUtils.generateQR(data);
        return image;
    }
    Future<void> scaneo(String tipo, String data) async {

      GenerarQR _qr = new GenerarQR(); 
      Image _s = await _qr.obtenerQRimagen(data);
      //Las funciones se llaman de diferentes calses.


      // aquí iría el código para convertir Image a Uint8List

      await Share.files(
        'esys images',
      {
        'esys.png': bytes1.buffer.asUint8List(),
        'bluedan.png': bytes2.buffer.asUint8List(),
        'addresses.csv': bytes3.buffer.asUint8List(),
      },//                EJEMPLO QUE DA LA LIBRERÍA
    '',
    text: 'My optional text.');

    }



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwnJt.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es un poco más complejo cuando trabajas con `Image` del tipo widget y no directamente de `dart:ui`, por lo que una solución sencilla es usar directamente el channel al que invoca el plugin.

Estuve revisando el plugin y la llamada sería así :

```dart
  final MethodChannel _channel =
      const MethodChannel('com.aeologic.adhoc.qr_utils');

 Future<Uint8List> obtenerQRimagen(String data) async{
       final Uint8List uInt8list =
        await _channel.invokeMethod('generateQR', {"content": data});
        return uInt8list;
    }


 Uint8List _s = await _qr.obtenerQRimagen(data);
```

Ahí tienes la variable `_s` ya obtiene directamente un `Uint8List`